# Jim Gates' discovery of error-correcting codes in equations of supersymmetry

Tags: supersymmetry, adinkras

Can anyone explain [*what's going on here*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924113235/http://www.onbeing.org/program/uncovering-codes-reality/1457), in a way that isn't just a lot of gee-whiz?

[*Here's the arXiv article.*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.0051)

I'm more of a computer science person than a physicist, so error-correcting codes are nothing new to me.

If he says there are such codes embedded in the equations of supersymmetry, what does that mean?

Can the encoded info be read? i.e. does the universe have a genome?

Do the equations contain errors?

What is the channel through which the codes are passed that might introduce errors?

How many errors per code block can be detected, and how many corrected?

Comment: 1. That the code is "embedded into the equations of supersymmetry" is probably just a very poetic way of saying that the code may be intepreted as describing a supersymmetric system, just like the toric code may be interpreted as describing a anyon string-net model on the torus. 2. What is the tag [tag:adinkras] supposed to mean?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I put in the tag hoping it would collect questions about this. If that's bad, I will take it out.

Comment: No idea if the tag is bad - but I simply have no idea what "adinkras" means. :)  If you just created it, you should fill in the tag wiki

Comment: @ACuriousMind: OK, I just did, but I guess it has to pass inspection. (Basically, it's an African word for a particular type of symbol. I'm sure you've seen lattice diagrams corresponding to Boolean systems, and Gates talks about manipulating these.)

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Adinkras are a type of graph Gates made to represent superalgebras.

See: http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0408004v1.pdf